# Handling Spanish Characters in R Scripts within Emacs

Tags: r, emacs

I'm encountering an issue while running an R script in Emacs, specifically when using a function with string literals containing Spanish accented characters. Here's the function in question:

```r
    fun.enfasis <- function(x) {
      fcase(
        x == "EARLY CHILDHOOD", "Educación Infantil",
        x == "READING COMPREHENSION", "Lectura Crítica",
        x == "ENGLISH", "Inglés",
        x == "PHYSICAL ED", "Educación Física",
        x == "SCIENCE", "Ciencias Naturales",
        x == "ARTS", "Artes",
        x == "QUANT REASONING", "Razonamiento cuantitativo"
      )
    }
```

When I try to run this script, I get the following error:

```
Error: invalid multibyte character in parser
```

The same code runs perfectly in RStudio, so I believe the issue is related to Emacs' handling of special characters in this context. Even though I'm opening the file with UTF-8 encoding, the error persists. I've included the error messages below for reference:

```r
> fun.enfasis <- function(x) {
+ fcase(
+ x == "EARLY CHILDHOOD", "Educación Infantil",
Error: invalid multibyte character in parser (<input>:3:36)
> x == "READING COMPREHENSION", "Lectura Crítica",
Error: unexpected ',' in "x == "READING COMPREHENSION","
> x == "ENGLISH", "Inglés",
Error: unexpected ',' in "x == "ENGLISH","
> x == "PHYSICAL ED", "Educación Física",
Error: unexpected ',' in "x == "PHYSICAL ED","
> x == "SCIENCE", "Ciencias Naturales",
Error: unexpected ',' in "x == "SCIENCE","
> x == "ARTS", "Artes",
Error: unexpected ',' in "x == "ARTS","
> x == "QUANT REASONING", "Razonamiento cuantitativo"
Error: unexpected ',' in "x == "QUANT REASONING","
> )
Error: unexpected ')' in ")"
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
>
```

Does anyone have suggestions on how to resolve this encoding issue in Emacs while running R scripts? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I've got no awesome answer for this, but I had a similar file with multibyte characters that triggered that error. Specifically, if I source the whole file (`C-c C-l` for `ess-load-file`) then it erred, but if I highlighted the region that contained the multibyte chars and sourced the _region_ (for me, `C-c C-r` for `ess-eval-region`) it worked and did _not_ produce the error. Eventually I tried something inane: I highlighted all text in the file, copied, then pasted into a new file (still in emacs, but new buffer); from there, `ess-load-file` worked, no idea why.

Comment: It might help to explicitly set the coding system for the file in buffer (`c-x RET r`), do the same for the format to save it (`c-x RET f`) and close/reopen file or revert-buffer.

Comment: Similar question has [an answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/74987/28451) at EmacsSE.

Comment: @Y. E. Thanks. That was the answer to my question.